# Android Soundpool Sound Keeps Playing over and over when the app is paused

Tags: android, audio

I have created a SoundPool that plays several sounds for my game. One sound in particular is played several times repentantly. When I close the app with the home button for example, the sound starts playing over and over really fast in the background. I have attempted to do this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    soundPool.autoPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    soundPool.autoResume();
}
```

hHis is how the sound is played:

```
soundPool.stop(jumpSound);
soundPool.play(jumpSound, 0.75f, 0.75f, 1, 0, 1f);
```

But the sound still plays when I close the app. What is the issue here?

Comment: @Override
public void onPause() {
    soundPool.autoPause(); super.onPause();
}

Comment: The sound still plays in the background.

Comment: What is youre loop value?

Comment: There is no loop. The game consists of a ball that bounces randomly. The sound is played when it bounces.

Comment: How you play youre sound?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66693/discussion-between-lobi-and-tastylemons).